# Is it possible to compile a class in memory from a String representation in an Android application?

Tags: java, android, runtime-compilation

I know that in Java is possible to compile a Java class at runtime on the fly (in memory) from a String representation. Afterwards, such class can be instantiated in the application. For example, some libraries providing support for this are BeanShell and commons-jci.

Is it possible to do the same in an Android application ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, however the tools to do so are not present on an Android device (Android does not actually use Java at runtime, only dalvik code derived therefrom), so a java-to-davlik-bytecode toolchain  capable of running on the device would have to be found/created/adapted and packaged in your application.  Most practical needs would have more direct possible solutions such as providing dalvik bytecode instead - unless your goal is to run user-entered java code.